# How to change Google Sign-in button language

Tags: javascript, internationalization, google-plus, google-signin

So here's my problem: I have a default Google Sign-in button in my page and need to change it's language.

I render it with:

```
gapi.signin2.render('google-button', {
    'scope': 'profile email',
    'width': 122,
    'height': 39, 
    ...
});
```

I've tried several solutions throughout the web. Those being:

1. Inserting lang object in the API's *script* tag:

   ```
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer > 
       {lang:'pt'}
   </script>
   ```
2. Setting ___gcfg:

   ```
   window.___gcfg = {
       lang: 'pt'
   };
   ```
3. Setting the *lang* attribute in the *html* tag

   ```
   <html lang="pt">
   ```
4. Adding a parameter to the API's URL

   ```
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?hl=pt" . . .
   ```

And the only place I found something about this in Google's documentation, it redirects to a page that says nothing about this. (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button)

I really would like to avoid building a custom button because of the branding guidelines, could someone help me?

PS: I'm using React.js

Many thanks!

Comment: Any solution even 2 years later? `hl` parameter is working only `withlongtitle: false`

Comment: @JérômeMEVEL how did you managed to use the hl parameter?

Comment: @Coil You can check my solution in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Using just with css:

```css
span[id^=not_signed_]:before {
  content: 'Connexion avec Google';
  padding-right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, I ended with that for now. Not really clean but "it works". So it uses a callback for the `platform.js` script:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=onLoadCallback" async defer></script>

<script>
    function onLoadCallback() {
        $('span[id^="not_signed_"]').html('Se connecter avec Google');
    }
</script>
```

As the span id is dynamic we have to use a "id start with" selector. (using jQuery in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Somebody asked in the comments how I managed to do it, so here is the answer.

I was also not able to get the `window.___gcfg` setting working but I managed to make the `hl` parameter to work.

`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?hl=pt" . . .`

To do that, when you call the `gapi.signin2.render(id, options)` function you must set  `longtitle: true` in the *options* parameter (default is *false*).

```
{
  scope: 'email',
  width: 200,
  height: 50,
  longtitle: true,
  theme: 'dark',
  onsuccess: handleSuccess,
  onfailure: handleFailure
}
```

Also pay attention to the *width*, as stated in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapisignin2renderid-options)

> longtitle
>
> Display long labels such as "Sign in with Google" rather than "Sign in" (default: false). When you use long titles, you should increase the width of the button from its default.

Answer (score -2):

In Google Sign-In for Websites you can change your language for button.

Only option are following instructions of this section:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button#building_a_button_with_a_custom_graphic

Comment: I don't see anywhere the option to set custom language for the button at specified link.

Comment: When I publish my comment I think that you can attach a query parameter lang in src of js. Now I think that scripts detect browser or device language and show in that language.

Comment: I guess we can change the text inside the span.buttonText with our own language. That's not an automatic solution, yet I solved it this way.